# How to make selenium wait until text in specific place

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have a question regarding selenium wait.
I want selenium to wait until a text displayed in specific xpath.
the text is: "Hensley and Workman Trading"
the xpath is: //td[@class='td_company ng-star-inserted']
I tried the wait until.attributeTobe function but can not make it wait.
What I am doing wrong (I think the until row is not working, the order or condition true)

```
public static void getWebElementByXpathWithWaitTextToBeSeen()
    {
        WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
      //  driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_WAITE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver2,EXPLICIT_WAITE);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath("//td[@class='td_company ng-star-inserted']"),"Hensley and Workman Trading","true"));
    }
```

From Dev Tool:
[image]

Comment: I know this isn't your question but I see the implicit wait logic commented out there. Be careful when mixing implicit and explicit waits as it may not have the expected effect.

Comment: I know this is in comment

Answer (score 4):

To wait for the text **Hensley and Workman Trading**  to be displayed within the *WebElement* you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[@class='td_company ng-star-inserted']"), "Hensley and Workman Trading"));
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI implements `wait.Until(expectedCondition)` functionality. Here's an example of what you're trying to do:

```
  public static void WaitForElementText(this IWebDriver driver, By by, string text)
  {
      var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeoutScope.Current.Timeout);
      wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(by).Text == text);
  }
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```
      var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeoutScope.Current.Timeout);
      wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@class='td_company ng-star-inserted']")).Text == text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```java
" Hensley and Workman Trading " // With the extra spaces
```

instead of

```java
"Hensley and Workman Trading"
```

Not positive, but those spaces may be throwing it off?

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath("//td[@class='td_company ng-star-inserted']"),"Hensley and Workman Trading","true"));  - Is this the correct syntax with "true"?\

Comment: I have not used Java with Selenium in years but that `"true"` does not seem correct when I'm reading the docs. I actually would recommend also checking out `attributeContains` instead of `attributeToBe`. Less brittle.

Comment: Docs say: **locator** - used to define WebElement to check its parameters
**attribute** - used to define css or html attribute
**value** - used as expected attribute value

Comment: There is also `textMatches` in the `ExpectedConditions` doc, which could be a really clean solution.